# Subquery in FROM cannot refer to other relations of same query level

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 4 tables from which I want to select data based on some conditions: `organisationunit,orgunitgroupmembers,orgunitgroup, orgunitgroupsetmember`

and the select code:

```
SELECT *
FROM   organisationunit,
       orgunitgroupmembers,
       orgunitgroup,
       orgunitgroupsetmembers
WHERE  organisationunit.comment = '1'
       AND orgunitgroupmembers.organisationunitid = organisationunit.organisationunitid
       AND orgunitgroup.orgunitgroupid = orgunitgroupmembers.orgunitgroupid
       AND orgunitgroupsetmembers.orgunitgroupid = orgunitgroup.orgunitgroupid
       AND orgunitgroupsetmembers.orgunitgroupsetid = '15633'
```

It does return what I want but now, I want to add these part

```
(select name 
 from organisationunit  tt 
 where tt.organisationunitid =organisationunit.parentid) as rayon
```

after the select method:

```
SELECT *
FROM   organisationunit,
       orgunitgroupmembers,
       orgunitgroup,
       orgunitgroupsetmembers,
       (SELECT NAME
        FROM   organisationunit tt
        WHERE  tt.organisationunitid = organisationunit.parentid) AS rayon
WHERE  organisationunit.comment = '1'
       AND orgunitgroupmembers.organisationunitid = organisationunit.organisationunitid
       AND orgunitgroup.orgunitgroupid = orgunitgroupmembers.orgunitgroupid
       AND orgunitgroupsetmembers.orgunitgroupid = orgunitgroup.orgunitgroupid
       AND orgunitgroupsetmembers.orgunitgroupsetid = '15633'
```

and it gives the error

> Subquery in FROM cannot refer to other relations of same query level

As you can see the table `organisationunit` has a `parentid`, which is a number and the same table `organisationunit` contains the name for that `parentid`. So I want at the end of the row in one column show the name of that `parentid`.

P.S I hope you got want I wanted, otherwise please feel free to ask the questions. Its first time that I do DB manipulations so far, if something is too obvious, believe me its NOT for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If am not wrong this is what you need. Here I made few changes.

Converted old style of join to proper `INNER JOIN` and moved the filters to `where` clause .

Next as mentioned in error you cannot refer the other tables in `from` clause of `subquery`. Actually you need to use `correlated subquery` to find the `parent name` or `self join`. or even a cross apply if it is supported

```
SELECT *,
       (SELECT NAME
        FROM   organisationunit tt
        WHERE  tt.organisationunitid = organisationunit.parentid) AS rayon
FROM   organisationunit
       INNER JOIN orgunitgroupmembers
               ON orgunitgroupmembers.organisationunitid = organisationunit.organisationunitid
       INNER JOIN orgunitgroup
               ON orgunitgroup.orgunitgroupid = orgunitgroupmembers.orgunitgroupid
       INNER JOIN orgunitgroupsetmembers
               ON orgunitgroupsetmembers.orgunitgroupid = orgunitgroup.orgunitgroupid
WHERE  organisationunit.comment = '1'
       AND orgunitgroupsetmembers.orgunitgroupsetid = '15633'
```

or even a `self join` to the same table to find the parent details.

```
SELECT *,
       tt.NAME AS rayon
FROM   organisationunit
       INNER JOIN orgunitgroupmembers
               ON orgunitgroupmembers.organisationunitid = organisationunit.organisationunitid
       INNER JOIN orgunitgroup
               ON orgunitgroup.orgunitgroupid = orgunitgroupmembers.orgunitgroupid
       INNER JOIN orgunitgroupsetmembers
               ON orgunitgroupsetmembers.orgunitgroupid = orgunitgroup.orgunitgroupid
       INNER JOIN organisationunit tt
               ON tt.organisationunitid = organisationunit.parentid
WHERE  organisationunit.comment = '1'
       AND orgunitgroupsetmembers.orgunitgroupsetid = '15633'
```

Comment: that was fast... I owe you a beer). It works.  How it calls in DB? what is the name of these technique? I want to learn how to do it. Inner joins? select *?

Comment: @Daler - Look for Inner Join,self Join & correlated subquery

Answer (score 0):

To get the name of the parent, use a self-join. Include one more reference to organisationunit in the from clause, with an alias tt or whatever. Something like this :

```
select A.*, B.*, C.*, D.*. tt.name as Rayon from organisationunit A,orgunitgroupmembers B,orgunitgroup C, orgunitgroupsetmembers D, organisationunit tt
where organisationunit.comment='1' 
and orgunitgroupmembers.organisationunitid=organisationunit.organisationunitid
and orgunitgroup.orgunitgroupid =orgunitgroupmembers.orgunitgroupid 
and orgunitgroupsetmembers.orgunitgroupid=orgunitgroup.orgunitgroupid
and orgunitgroupsetmembers.orgunitgroupsetid='15633'
and  tt.organisationunitid =A.organisationunit.parentid
```

Of course, you may want to note that if the datasets are large, self-join may have some performance issues, in that case, you can use multi-step operation after selecting into temporary tables or whatever.